# Tesla AC motor: what is this component?

Tags: power-supply, motor, electromagnetism

Can anyone explain how the pictured component that looks like a long stem connecting to the generator G operates? Most specifically of the left side connecting to the terminals?

[image]

My understanding is that there are two pairs of wires L and L’ from the stem to each pair of electromagnets.  There is also two pairs of wires connecting from a 2-phase generator which provide the corresponding voltage (sine/cos) to rotate the magnetic field.

I think the stem in question also operates under some single phase power, shown by the two terminals at the tip. The stem has a positive/negative pair for one phase lol’ connected to an electromagnet, while the other pair L’ is positive and what appears to be a common or ground return from the second electromagnet through the valve stem exterior and to the right (is it a sheath of a conductor?).

Here is the full picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'stem' is a shaft \$a^\prime\$ that is being rotated by a prime mover (eg steam engine) off to the right of the diagram but not shown.

The two rotating windings on the armature of the generator are arranged to generate AC voltages with both phases approximately 90° out of phase (not critical).

The wires (L and L’) are routed through the hollow shaft to the slip rings and then to brushes that transfer the power to the two phase induction motor on the left of the diagram. There it creates a rotating magnetic field that in turn causes the rotor to rotate.

From the diagram shown in the question the position of the coils in the generator are not obvious. This is another diagram in the patent showing them more clearly:

[image]

Image credit: [suiter.com/patent-of-the-day-electro-magnetic-motor/](https://suiter.com/patent-of-the-day-electro-magnetic-motor/)

Comment: I’m having trouble seeing the generator’s two perpendicular coils. I see the black loops, but they appear loops on the same plane, where current moves back and forth top to bottom going through the field. Do you see different? Also, looking at the first picture and following right to left the magnet top and bottom has a zig zag pattern. Look at the beginning on the right and compare top and bottom. Is this sine and cosine, suggesting the wave form?

Comment: I think the picture of the generator shows two loops, top and bottom, and the two waveforms over the magnets indicates the field to induce on each loop which is 90 degrees out of phase. This would provide a pair of voltage waveforms due to changing magnetic field and this drives the rotational field.

Comment: @Nick - look at the other diagrams in the patent - I've added one that shows the coils more clearly.